# Rails - doing an integration test and want to go to a has many path but not sure how to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `guides` which have many `categories` and my fixtures have guides and categories in them with the category fixtures having guide_id columns so the has many association is linked.

I want to go to a certain guides add new category path in the integration test which has a url path like this /guide/guide1/categories/new problem is if I just use `get new_guide_category_path` it doesn't specify which guides to use (which guides new category path). Do I do something like `get new_guide_category_path(:guide1)`?

Sorry if its hard to understand what I'm asking, I wanted to ask this before I went to sleep

Comment: You should pass respected **guide instance**, `get new_guide_category_path(@guide)` where `@guide` can be like `Guide.find(1)`

Answer (score 0):

The url helpers work the same way within the test environment as the development/live environment.

You will need to create a guide first, then pass that into the helper.

```
guide = Guide.create
get new_guide_category_path(guide)
```